# VASP input file for formation energy calculation

Tags: density-functional-theory, vasp, software-input-file-request

I want to calculate the formation energy of $\ce{Mg2Si}$ using VASP. What should be the initial steps to perform this run? What `INCAR` tags are required? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: +1 But please take a look at the edits I made, especially the tags that I added and the `$\ce{ }$` that I used for the formatting of your chemical formula.

Comment: @NikeDattani Thanks for editing my question and make it more clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your structure is relaxed. The total energy can be calculated with a self-consistent calculation.

An `INCAR` template you may refer to:

```
System:
ISTART=0 
ICHARG=2  
ENCUT=500   
EDIFF=1E-6    
NELM=300  
ISMEAR=0   
SIGMA=0.05       
IALGO=38    

##Spin-related
#ISPIN=2  
#MAGMOM=17*0        
#LSORBIT=.TRUE.      
#SAXIS= 0 0 1     
#ISYM=0   

##Output:
LCHARG=.TRUE.
LWAVE=.TRUE.
```

PS: For the formation energy calculation, you need to find the lowest-energy configuration of bulk Mg and Si.

And this post also may helpful: [How to calculate the formation energy of a monolayer using VASP?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/4381/how-to-calculate-the-formation-energy-of-a-monolayer-using-vasp/4382#4382)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for reply . Could you please tell should I take primitive cell for finding lowest ground state energy or conventional cell for Mg2Si , Mg, Si ? I am following one question asked here only where formation energy is calculated for MgCu2 where user take conventional cell of 24 atoms .

Comment: Technically, it doesn't matter. Just check the formula of formation energy, we often use the eV/atom as the unit.